# Spring-Batch csv-file with related other csv-files

Tags: java, database, spring-batch

Read product data from csv-files via Spring Batch and import the data into the DB.
CSV-Files:
product.csv
Id, Name
1, product1
2, product2
product-attributes.csv (sorted after product ids)
productid, name
1, width
1, height
1, weight
2, width
2, height
...

Is it possible to do it with spring batch?

My idea of the flow is:
`FlatFileItemReader` (product) reads a line, then a `FlatFileItemReader` (product-attributes) reads all lines with `id=productId`
The processor creates a product entity with existing attributes
The writer writes the product entity with cascading in the database.

Is this possible? Is the use of `CompositeReader` the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example for spring batch. Input-Process-Output is the kind of processing SpringBatch is geared toward. [Take a look at this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) - I think it follows exactly what you want to do. Define your reader with comma as your separator, define your writer as your database insert.

In answer to your specific question, yes a composite reader would help because you are reading from 2 files. [See these examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader). You could also implement your writer to read both files and remove the requirement for the composite reader. How you implement this will be based on how you want to process your data. I believe the composite reader will read a chunk of the first file and then a chunk of the second file and then move to the processing part.

[Here is another SO related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373455/spring-batch-compositeitemreader-and-compositeitemwritter-examples-unable-to) you may benefit from reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can load each file in a staging table, join data from those tables and write the joined results in the target table.

Another way to do it is to use a `SystemCommandTasklet` to join the files with the `join` command (on unix systems or an equivalent on ms windows) then configure a chunk-oriented step that reads the joined file and load it in the database.

Hope this helps.